# Incompatibility of types when they appear to be the same, in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript app and I'm facing a situation where the types appear to me to be exactly the same, but I get an error saying that "`Type ...NotebookTools.Tool is not assignable to type ...NotebookTools.Tool`", then "`Property __ is protected but type 'Tool' is not a class derived from 'Tool'`"

Please let me know what could be causing this issue!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Correct message you are getting in the screenshot

The path to `NotebookTools.Tool` is different between the compared types and is visible in the screenshot, i.e one is in the `node_modules` and the other is in your `src` folder.

Comment: Even though I saw that the paths were different, your note made me realize that I had created a local file and changed the type, and then had inconsistent imports, thanks!